# Ip address of PC in USB Tethering mode in Android without WIFI, Programatically

Tags: android, usb, ip

How can I programatically get the Ip address, default gateway and port number of the PC to which the android phone is connected in USB Tethering mode, without using WIFI Manager?

I used network interfaces, but it doesnt give me the correct information, is there any other way?

```
for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements();) {
            NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();
            for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf.getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements();) {
                InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();
                if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress()) {
                    address += inetAddress.getHostAddress().toString() ;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9906021/getting-the-ip-address-of-client-or-getting-the-informationssid-of-clients-con?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok here is the round about solution that I reached, from the address received through the network interface, I remove the last section in the address, like 192.168.1.40, i remove 40 and iterate through a loop starting from 192.168.1.0 and find out the port which actually connects. The snippet is below

```
for(idx=0; idx <=255; idx++)
         {
             try
             {
                 t[idx] = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            str = IPpart + "." + idx;
                                            socket = new Socket(str, PORT);
                                   IP = socket.getInetAddress().toString();
                             Gateway = socket.getLocalAddress().toString();
                        }
                    });
                 t[idx].setName("IPclass");
                 t[idx].start();
                 if(IP != "")
                 {
                     closeThread();
                     break;
                 }
             }catch(Exception ex){ }
         }
```