# Can an Android app get access to the MAC address of devices trying to connect to its hotspot?

Tags: android, networking

Suppose say an android phones hotspot is switched on,can an application running on the phone get access to the MAC addresses of the different devices that are trying to connect to it?

Comment: Looks like you could use a good google search? Marking your question as duplicate of this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16998095/list-connected-devices-to-android-phone-working-as-wifi-access-point

Comment: this is about connected devices,I need all the devices whose wifi is switched on and are pinging their MAC addresses

Answer (score 0):

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo wInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
String macAddress = wInfo.getMacAddress();
```

Also, add below permission in your manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
```

reference on [stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10831640/3678308)

Comment: This gives the MAC id of our device, i need the mac ids of those devices which are within the hotspot region and who are pinging their MAC ids