# (android) how to determine the ip address of connected devices in android hotspot

Tags: android, ip, wifi

i am writing an android app to control other devices if other devices is connected to my android phone's Wifi hotspot. However, i am unable to determine the ip address of the connected devices (say another android phone). Therefore, i am asking a way to determine the ip address of connected devices in my wifi hotspot. Thank you in advance

Comment: This page may help you to find your answer. 

http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/46649/how-to-get-the-information-of-users-connected-to-a-wi-fi-hotspot

Comment: But can i determine the ip in api method?? i would like to do it in automatically way

Comment: Try this code on the below link. 

http://stackoverflow.com/a/7049074/3847529

Answer (score 1):

You can try [this](https://github.com/rkp13/android-testhotspot/blob/master/TestHotspot/src/com/mady/wifi/api/wifiAddresses.java#L442) method for getting the list of devices connected to your hotspot. for pingCmd refer [this](https://github.com/rkp13/android-testhotspot/blob/master/TestHotspot/src/com/mady/wifi/api/wifiAddresses.java#L120)

```
public ArrayList<String> getArpLiveIps(boolean onlyReachables) {
            BufferedReader bufRead = null;
            ArrayList<String> result = null;

            try {
                    result = new ArrayList<String>();
                    bufRead = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/proc/net/arp"));
                    String fileLine;
                    while ((fileLine = bufRead.readLine()) != null) {


                            String[] splitted = fileLine.split(" +");

                              if ((splitted != null) && (splitted.length >= 4)) {

                                    String mac = splitted[3];
                                     if (mac.matches("..:..:..:..:..:..")) {
                                          boolean isReachable = pingCmd(splitted[0]);/**
 * Method to Ping  IP Address    
 * @return true if the IP address is reachable
 */
                                         if (!onlyReachables || isReachable) {
                                                    result.add(splitted[0]);
                                            }
                                    }
                            }
                    }
            } catch (Exception e) {

            } finally {
                    try {
                        bufRead.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {

                    }
            }

            return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If your stock Android Hotspot app does not have this option. Use this app

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.etustudio.android.hotspotmanager

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no official API for the hotspot, but you could use reflection, even though it might be difficult.

Also check out [IP address of device using phone as access point](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8324215/3975480)

Comment: Yes, i am looking for an api to perform the job done

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i actually try this post before but not work

Comment: Your're welcome ;)
But as mentioned, there is no official API. You'll need a lot of effort to build your own if you want so.