# Getting the IP address of client or getting the information(SSID) of Clients connected to Hotspot Android (after Tethering)

Tags: android

I got the program for Wifi tethering which i got a open (non secured) hot spot in Android. I like to view the details of client (SSID and IP address) connected to my hotspot. 
I used SocketAddress socketid=socket.getLocalSocketAddress(); and also used

```
public  void getLocalIpAddressString() {
   try {
       for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements();) {
          NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();
          for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf.getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements();) {
                InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();
               if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress()) {
                   // return inetAddress.getHostAddress().toString();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), inetAddress.getHostAddress().toString(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
           }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      Log.e("IPADDRESS", ex.toString());
   }
  // return null;
   }
```

These will return only the local IP but can you please help me in getting the IP address of client connected to my Wifi Hotspot. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I got the response for getting the Client IP connected to my hotspot. The code below will track the Mac and IP changes each time a new client is added to my network

```
public void getClientList() {

    int macCount = 0;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/proc/net/arp"));
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] splitted = line.split(" +");

            if (splitted != null && splitted.length >= 4) {
                // Basic sanity check
                String mac = splitted[3];

                if (mac.matches("..:..:..:..:..:..")) {
                    macCount++;
                    ClientList.add("Client(" + macCount + ")");
                    IpAddr.add(splitted[0]);
                    HWAddr.add(splitted[3]);
                    Device.add(splitted[5]);
                    Toast.makeText(
                            getApplicationContext(),
                            "Mac_Count  " + macCount + "   MAC_ADDRESS  "
                                    + mac, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    for (int i = 0; i < splitted.length; i++)
                        System.out.println("Addressssssss     "
                                + splitted[i]);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: `cat /proc/net/arp` was what I needed to be reminded of, thanks.

Comment: is this code working for any android 2.x and above?
@ShyamDev

Answer (score 0):

you searched in java.net? It is also listed in the android dev...

Comment: Fabian I checked the codes but I am unable to find any suitable code that can control the connected clients to my hotspot or atleast even to view the details of them