# get ip address of bluetooth tethering device on android

Tags: android, bluetooth, ip, gateway

I have a specific problem:
I have a Android 1.6 device that uses bluetooth to connect to a smartphone (android) and use tethering to access internet...
Bluetooth itself cannot be used for anything else except that connection.
It also doesn't have a wifi.

Now, I'm trying to make an app for that device that will connect to a "server" app on the smartphone!
What is the easiest way of doing this? I have a simular app running but I have to manualy type the IP of the "server" (if smartphone is on wifi).
Can I somehow programatically get the IP of the tethering smartphone or something if it using bluetooth tethering?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You could run a terminal emulator on your smartphone and try running the following commands:

- getprop net.dns1
- ip addr show
- ip route show
- netcfg

Perhaps you can run those commands from within your app? Otherwise, you would have to read through the Android API manual, which can be found [here.](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-1.6.html)

UPDATE: as of Android Nougat 7.x, ifconfig is present, and netcfg is gone.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6289714/ip-address-of-pc-in-usb-tethering-mode-in-android-without-wifi-programatically?rq=1), also seems to be related and may be of use.